# Display html text in codenameone

Tags: codenameone

I would like to display html formatted text that I have as a string.
Does the WebBroswer component support this ?
If yes, what method to use ?
Thanks,
Sanket

Code:

```
private void loadCourseDesc() {
    Container courseDescContainer = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    NETextArea title = new NETextArea(AppState.current_Course.getTitle());
    title.setUIID("biggreylabel");
    courseDescContainer.addComponent(title);
    Container c1 = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
    Label l = new Label("Fees:" + AppState.current_Course.getFees());
    l.setUIID("mgreylabel");
    c1.addComponent(l);
    Label l1 = new Label("Completion Date:" + AppState.current_Course.getExpiryDate());
    l1.setUIID("mgreylabelLM");
    c1.addComponent(l1);
    courseDescContainer.addComponent(c1);
    WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser(){

        @Override
        public void onLoad(String url) {
            super.onLoad(url); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            instance.forceRevalidate();
        }

    };
    wb.setScrollableY(true);
    System.out.println("::---" + AppState.current_Course.getDesc());

    wb.setPage(AppState.current_Course.getDesc(), "http://localhost/");
    courseDescContainer.addComponent(wb);
    replace(courseDescContainer);
```

Code for replace:

```
private void replace(final Container c) {
    Display.getInstance().callSerially(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            instance.replaceAndWait(currentCentre, c, null);
            currentCentre = c;
            instance.forceRevalidate();
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It supports it by adding the component into the container, to set HTML instead of a URL just use `setPage` instead of `setURL`.

Comment: I was actually using setPage, but it wasn't working. The base container which contained the web browser component was getting rendered using a fade transition. I removed the transition and it started working. How do I get it work with the transition. I have edited the question with the source code.

Comment: Also, it works on the emulator, but not on the phone. I am testing on MotoX. It simply shows blank.

Comment: What is the layout you are using? Are you sure the HTML is valid for the device? Devices are far more sensitive to HTML content than the desktop.

Comment: I am using a box layout with different items. It also has a web browser component. The html content is very basic. I think the problem is that the device is not displaying the web browser within box layout with other items. If i have the web browser in a border layout at center then it works. what could be going wrong ?

Comment: Since the browser is calculating its preferred size asynchronously (after parsing on the browser thread) the size during layout is 0. You have two options (other than switching layouts): 1. Use setPreferredSize(). 2. Revalidate after the onLoad event.

Comment: setPreferredSize() is something that I dont want to use for obvious reasons. Revalidating after onLoad is not working on the device

Comment: Try using the forceRevalidate() method of form in the onLoad() method.

Comment: If you use replaceAndWait and then the forceRevalidate does that work? The replace is asynchronous hence the revalidate after it makes no sense.

Comment: Nope. doesn't work on motox. Please check the question section for my code for replace

Comment: Where do you take the onLoad event into consideration in that code?

Comment: Edited the question again

Comment: Hi Shai...the html component seems to work only when it placed in a border layout. In other layout, its just on working.

Comment: Sorry for not getting back on this, I directed it at our Android guys and it got buried there. We will need some standalone test case to reproduce this I suggest filing an issue at http://code.google.com/p/codenameone/issues/list